# ArrayList size() Java

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> legend=new ArrayList<>(10);
 for (int i=0;i<legend.size();i++){ 

            legend.set(i,null); 

        }
```

Я с помощью конструктора указал кол-во элементов в массиве и хочу их обнулить. Но size() выдает только кол-во добавленных в массив элементов(т.е. в моем случае 0). А как взять это число, которое я указывал в конструкторе. Не хочу постоянно писать цифры, хочется метод какой-то.

Comment: Не уверен, что его получите, по-крайней мере, в описании класса нет поля/метода для его получения: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)

Comment: Это не количество элементов в массиве, это количество памяти выделенной для хранения элементов. Пока вы не добавили элементы, их там нет и обнулять тоже нечего. Вы можете добавить в список `null`-ы, с помощью `legend.add(null)`, но это можно сделать и больше 10 раз. Число 10 в конструкторе гарантирует, что добавление 10 элементов не потребует перевыделения памяти и каждое добавление будет происходить за константное время.

Comment: понял, спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. У реализаций `List` в `Java` есть такое свойство как `capacity` - значение, которое указывает ваш зарезервированный объем памяти. Это **не фактический размер коллекции**, а лишь зарезервированное место в памяти.

Разработчики не предоставили методов для получения этого свойства.

Получить его можно только с помощью `Reflections`, чего естественно делать не рекомендую

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> strings = 
            new ArrayList<>(10);
    
    System.out.println(getCapacity(strings)); // 10
}

public static int getCapacity(List list) throws Exception {
    final Field field =
            ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return ((Object[]) field.get(list)).length;
}
```